# Error with json in Azure Machine Learning Studio with R with H2O package

Tags: r, h2o, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-notebooks

I am deploying a model using the H2O package with R on an Azure Machine Learning Studio notebook.

I understand that when requesting my predict function the data goes in json format, and when the as.h2o () command inside the mypred function tries to convert json to h2o format it can't and occurs an error

## Train the model

```
logistica_h2o <- h2o.glm(x = X, y = Y, 
                         training_frame = treino.h2o, 
                         family = "binomial)
```

## get workspace ID and token and

```
workspace_id <- ""
authorization_token <- ""
ws <- workspace(workspace_id, authorization_token)
```

## create my predict function

```
newdata <- dados[,-32] #Remove response variable 

mypredict <- function(newdata){
  library(h2o)
  newdata <- as.h2o(newdata)
  as.data.frame(h2o.predict(logistica_h2o, newdata))
}
```

## here I publish the service

```
ep <- publishWebService(ws = ws,
 fun = mypredict, 
 name = "PredicaoDeEntradaDeRonda", 
 inputSchema = dados[,-32], 
 data.frame=T)
```

## The problems occurs here

```
ewdata <-treino.h2o[1,-32]

pred <- consume(ep, newdata)
```

```
Error: No method asJSON S3 class: H2OFrame Traceback:

consume(ep, newdata)
callAPI(apiKey, requestUrl, requestsLists, globalParam, retryDelay, . .retry = .retry)
charToRaw(paste(toJSON(req, auto_unbox = TRUE, digits = 16), . collapse = "\n"))
paste(toJSON(req, auto_unbox = TRUE, digits = 16), collapse = "\n")
toJSON(req, auto_unbox = TRUE, digits = 16)
asJSON(x, dataframe = dataframe, Date = Date, POSIXt = POSIXt, . factor = factor, complex = complex, raw = raw, matrix = matrix, . auto_unbox = auto_unbox, digits = digits, na = na, null = null, . force = force, indent = indent, ...)
asJSON(x, dataframe = dataframe, Date = Date, POSIXt = POSIXt,
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert `newdata` into an R data.frame before passing it to the `consume()` function:

```
newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
```

This looks like the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49415285/5451344